# Extracting second value of each sublist

Tags: list-manipulation

How can one get the second value of every array inside the outside array?
I have the following data `data = {{10, 20}, {30, 40}, {50, 60}};`

I want to extract `20`, `40` and `60` from it. I have tried the following:

```
data = {{10, 20}, {30, 40}, {50, 60}};

data2 = data[[{1, 2, 3}]][[2]]
```

> ```
> {30, 40}
> ```

But that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Kuba I think this one is much closer to RTFM than to that question. May be we want to keep this one though, this is a common question.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin So you say "simple mistake" :)? I think you're right, it is 5th example for `Part` documentation so it is a good reason to close. Marking it a duplicate will not help I think, It will be hard to find this question in the future, with this title - impossible.

Comment: @Kuba Yes, I think it's right.

Comment: @Kuba perhaps with a different title it might serve as an entry point,  even if it *is* RTFM.

Comment: @YvesKlett I've retracted my "duplicate" vote so now it's up to community :)

Answer (score 2):

Many ways to achieve that. Any of the following (and many more)

```
data[[All,2]] 
Last/@data 
Transpose[data][[2]]
```

should do the trick.